# How to save and edit images by ckeditor in Laravel 8

Tags: laravel-8, ckeditor4.x

I am saving some images which created & upload by CKEditor in my Laravel application and it getting saved properly. But when I want to edit the content, sometimes I am getting the content from DB and load it into CKEditor.

But Most of the cases, the page loading & loading ..... And The content not loads. Sometimes loads properly, but see the string as the attached image below.

[image]

How to solve this error!!

```html
 <textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" rows="20">{{ $portfolio_data->long_desc}}</textarea>
```

```
 <textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" rows="20">{{ $portfolio_data->long_desc}}</textarea>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use {!! !!} for loading page content in blade engine in laravel instead of  {{ }}
write like this:

```html
<textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" rows="20">{!! $portfolio_data->long_desc !!}</textarea>
```

Answer (score -1):

There is a needed value

```
<textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" value="{!! $portfolio_data->long_desc !!}" rows="20"></textarea>
```

Comment: <textarea name="long_desc" class="form-control" id="summernote" value="{!! $portfolio_data->long_desc !!}" rows="20"></textarea>

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).